# log4net smtpappender <from> not working

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I am using log4net and i have added smtpappender , i am not able to understand the use of  as the mail sent is still from abc@gmail.com and thr buffer is also not working

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="def@gmail.com" />
  <from value="xyz@gmail.com" />
  <subject value="Error logging message" />
  <smtpHost value="smtp.gmail.com" />
  <port value="587"/>
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <username value="abc@gmail.com"/>
  <password value="password"/>
  <EnableSsl value="true" />
  <bufferSize value="512" />
  <lossy value="false"/>
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="WARN" />
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName} :: %level :: 
                      %message %newlineLogger: %logger%newlineThread: %thread%newlineDate: 
                      %date%newlineNDC: %property{NDC}%newline%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: buffer is not working and in recieved email "from" is still "abc@gmail.com"
then what is the use of <to> property ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging into the smtp server from google with email account abc@google.com. The smtp server does not allow you to send mails from xyz@google.com. This is probably because of possible spamming if it was allowed. The problem is not in the smtpappender, it is working as designed. The google smtp server is configured so you can only send mails from your own account.

Comment: Thank you , that actually solved my problem . I had to make some changes in smtp server account.
And what about the buffer , i am getting mail for every single error ,whatever maybe the buffersize